# how to solve comma separated values in struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts

I have a JSP which has user to create items.

After creation I am showing them in the same page in a table along with two button say update and delete.

When the user changes the values and clicks on update the value is changing and displaying add with the first row column value+ changed value in comma separated.

Can any one please tell me why its happening and how to solve that.

Find the below jsp file

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function updateRow(id) {
var manufacturer = document.getElementById("manufacturer").value;   
var family = document.getElementById("family").value;
                var model = document.getElementById("model").value;

        var url = "id="+id+"&manufacturer="+manufacturer+"&model="+model+"&family="+family;
            document.globalForm.action= "http://localhost:8080/ContentInventory/update.action?id=" + id + "&manufacturer="+ manufacturer + "&model=" + model + "&family=" + family;
        document.globalForm.submit(); 
    }

    function deleteRow(id) {
        document.globalForm.action = "http://localhost:8080/ContentInventory/delete.action?id="+id;
        document.globalForm.submit();

    }

    function addDetails() {
    document.globalForm.action = "http://localhost:8080/ContentInventory/add.action";
alert(document.globalForm.action);
document.globalForm.submit();

    }
</script>

<html>

<body>

    <h1>Global Handset Compatibility</h1>
    <s:actionerror />

    <s:form id="globalForm" name="globalForm" method="post" theme="simple" >
        <table>

            <tr>
                <td><s:label value="Manufacturer" />
                </td>
                <td><s:textfield name="manufacturer" label="Manufacturer" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><s:label value="Model" />
                </td>
                <td><s:textfield name="model" label="Model" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><s:label value="Family" />
                </td>
                <td><s:textfield name="family" label="Family" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <!--<s:submit value="Add Inventory" align="center" />-->
                <input type="button" value="Add Inventory" id="addButton" onclick="javascript:addDetails()" >
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>





        <h2>Inventory List</h2>
    <table id="global" border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Manufacturer</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Family</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
            <th>Edit/Update</th>
        </tr>

        <s:if test="%{globalList.size() > 0}">
            <s:iterator value="globalList" id="globals">

                <tr>


                    <td align="center">
                    <s:textfield id="manufacturer" name="#globals.manufacturer" /></td>

                    <td align="center"><s:textfield id="model" name="#globals.model" /></td>



                    <td align="center"><s:textfield id="family" name="#globals.family" /></td>

                    <td align="center"><input type="button" value="Delete" id="deleteButton" onclick="javascript:deleteRow('<s:property value="id"/>')">
</td>
                    <td align="center">
                                        <input type="button"  value="Update" id="updateButton<s:property value="id"/>"  onclick="javascript:updateRow('<s:property value="id"/>')">

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </s:iterator>

        </s:if>
        <s:else>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">No Data Found</td>
            </tr>
        </s:else>

    </table>
        </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

And in action class i have getter and setter methods for the fields and while clicking the update button i am getting the updated values using js and sending to the back-end. The values are inserting correctly but while displaying the page it shows the vales with comma separated with first and second vales as well which is incorrect...

Thanks for your responses

Comment: You need to post the action code and/or struts configuration file. Without it seems not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me the other day. It turns out that I had multiple fields with same name.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`id` attribute in `iterator`s is deprecated, use `var` instead.

I'm not sure what you are asking here, but if you are iterating a List, and you want to refer uniquely to an element of that list (either when posting, or when getting values via javascript), you need to use the index:

```
<s:iterator value="globalList" var="globals" status="ctr">

   <s:textfield id="manufacturer" name="globalList[#ctr.index].manufacturer" />

   <s:textfield id="model" name="globalList[#ctr.index].model" />

   <s:textfield id="family" name="globalList[#ctr.index].family" />
```

etc...

You can use the IteratorStatus to generate unique HTML `id` fields too (otherwise it will be no valid HTML), like:

```
<s:textfield id="manufacturer_num_%{#ctr.index}" 
             name="globalList[#ctr.index].manufacturer" />
```

this way you can refer uniquely to each field:

```
var manufacturer = document.getElementById("manufacturer_num_" + counter).value;
```

of course for this to work you'll need to pass the `counter` var to the javascript function.

As a final thought, using the index inside iterated elements, you won't need any javascript nor single posts anymore to **update** the values: just declare a `List<yourObject>`
in the Action, and post all the grid, the List will be populated automatically with the rows from your JSP;
you will need to refer to a single element only for **delete** method, for security reasons too.